# How To draw A rangechart and candle stick chart in android in android?

Tags: android, graph

i want to draw a rangechart and candle stick in android i search the whole web but cant find a solution the char is as shown below
[image: Rangechart]

[image: candlestickgraph]

<s>please find a solution</s>

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/

Answer (score 4):

This may help you ;). [Screenshotz](http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html)

this contain all type of charts.... sample [code](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/)